# Making Calls to Grafana Local Instance from Express Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, grafana

I'm trying to build an Express server that will send requests to my local Grafana instance to setup a datasource (PGDB) and then a custom dashboard that I will receive and display the charts on my front-end.

I've gotten the requests sent from postman to my local Grafana instance to work but they're not working when coming from my Express back-end.

The error I'm receiving:

> TypeError: fetch failed: error in the grafanaController.createDataSource

```
createDataSource: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { graf_name, graf_pass, graf_port, db_name, db_url, db_username, db_server, db_password } =   req.body;
    const url = `http://localhost:${graf_port}/api/datasources`;

const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${graf_name}:${graf_pass}`).toString('base64')}`,
        // "Connection" : "keep-alive",
        // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      },
      body: {
        name: `${db_name}`,
        type: 'postgres',
        url: `${db_url}`,
        user: `${db_username}`,
        access: 'proxy',
        database: `${db_server}`,
        secureJsonData: {
          password: `${db_password}`
          },
        basicAuth: false
      }
    };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, config);
    const data = await response.json();
  catch (error) {
    return next({
       log: `${error}: error in the grafanaController.createDataSource`,
       status: 400,
       message: `${error}: error with the data source`
     })
   }
```

I tried adding all the additional headers that are commented out in the code. I added settings to the custom.ini file to allow any origins. I've console logged every variable, all the information is correct.

Comment: Can you print the `error` to check the full error stack?

Comment: Seems to be solved for my group members, they're using mac and I'm on windows.